# Why am I getting *uninitialized* warning when I call a function in php?

Tags: php

```
PHP   1. {main}() /Users/aaron/NetBeansProjects/PhpProject2/CssToSQL.php:0
PHP   2. GetContentRules($contentRules = *uninitialized*) /Users/aaron/NetBeansProjects/PhpProject2/CssToSQL.php:134

Line 134: $contentRuleList = GetContentRules($configSections['vips']);

function GetContentRules($contentRules) { ... }
```

`$configSections['vips']` contains like 1114 lines

My function works as expected, but I'm trying to figure out why this error is thrown?

TIA!

Comment: Please be more clear and specific.

Comment: Try `var_dump($configSections);` before calling function, is `$configSections['vips']` is defined?

Answer (score 0):

Error != warning. A warning is simply an indication of something you SHOULD fix, but don't HAVE to. If it was an error, your script would bomb out at the point the error occured. Given the error message you're sort of hinting at in the question title, your `$configSections['vips']` is not defined. Either `$configSections` itself isn't, or there's no `['vips']` key in the array.

Comment: However, in some places fixing a warning may lead to fix a problem. In other words, sometimes a warning may hide a future error.

Comment: Hello. Yes, Thank you for the feedback. I do indeed know the difference between an error and a warning, however, I typed error and meant warning. My bad. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: I did find the issue BTW. I was calling an index for an array that was out of bounds in each case that I had the warning. Again, thank you all for your time and consideration.